# Should the input format of keras model fit and evaluate be strictly consistent?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I use keras to set up a neural network for recommendation. I use many features of training data to fit the model. Then I need to evaluate it using test data. Usually, when testing a recommender system with testing data, less data will be used. So my question is should the input format of keras model `fit()` and `evaluate()` be strictly consistent? Specifically:

```
fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1,
    callbacks=[], validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None,
    shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None)
evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None)
```

When do `model.fit()` you put many feature and information into input `x` to train the neural network. When do `model.evaluate()`, like MF in recommender system, test data only have less information. So the input of `model.fit()` and `model.evaluate()` should be the same format?

I would appreciate a simple example.

Comment: This seems very broad. Please provide more details and/or code.

Comment: fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, callbacks=[], validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None)   evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None ) When do model.fit you put many feature and information into input x to train the neural network .When do model.evaluate, like MF in recommender system ,test data only have less information. So the input of model.fit and model.evaluate x should be the same format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general the `x` of `fit`, `evaluate` and `predict` must have the same format, and the `y` of `fit` and `evaluate` too.

I must necessarily be like this. If your model is trained to use some feature present in the training data to determine the output but that same feature is not present later for evaluation of prediction, how would your model possibly work?

If you have some input features that are somehow used during training but not during evaluation of prediction, you will still have to adapt the data to the same format; you could either pad the input as necessary with zeros or split the input in different parts with a [multi-input model](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) and give default values for the missing inputs as necessary.